# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ exists

Tags: limits

Let $S_1 = 1$ and $S_{n+1} = (\frac{n}{n+1})S_n^2$ for $n \geq 1$

I am asked to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ exists

I am wondering whether or not I solve for $S_n$ and then let $S_{n+2} \leq S_{n+1}$ by plugging in $n+2$ for $n$

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy to see that $S_n > 0$ for all $n$. Prove, by induction on $n \geq 2$, that $\displaystyle S_n \leq \frac{1}{n}$. It follows that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n = 0$.

ADDED LATER: For $n \geq 2$,

$$
S_n \leq \frac{1}{n} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad S_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} S_n^2 \leq \frac{n}{n+1} \bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^2 = \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \leq \frac{1}{n+1}
$$

Comment: Could you please show how to do the induction step to show that $S_n\le \frac{1}{n}$ - thanks.

Comment: @user84413: Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you - I was getting confused when I tried this, and now I can see it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

a) First show by induction that $0<S_n\le1$ for all $n$.

b) Then show by induction that $S_{n+1}<S_n$ for all $n$.

Now you can conclude that you have a decreasing sequence that is bounded below.

Comment: can you explain more? thank you

Comment: The inequality $0<S_n\le1$ is clear when $n=1$, and if it's true for an integer $n\ge1$, then it is true for $n+1$ since it is not hard to show that $S_{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}S_{n}^{2}$ satisfies $0<S_{n+1}\le1$ if $0<S_n\le 1$.  Then you can use the inequality from part a) to show by induction that $S_{n+1}<S_{n}$ for all n by induction.  Once you have shown you have a bounded monotonic sequence, you can conclude that it converges.

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$
S_1=1,\,\,S_2=\frac{1}{2},
$$
and $S_{n+1}<S_n^2$, for all $n$. Hence
$$
0<S_n<S_{n-1}^2<S_{n-2}^{2^2}<S_{n-3}^{2^3}<S_2^{2^{n-2}}=2^{-2^{n-2}}.
$$
Now, $2^{n-2}>n-2$, for all $n$, and hence
$$
0<S_n<\frac{1}{2^{n-2}},
$$ 
which implies that $S_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a particularly fast way to do it:  $0\leq S_n\leq 1$ for all $n$, so $S_{n+1}\leq \frac{n}{n+1} S_n \leq \frac{n}{n+1} \cdot \frac{n-1}{n} S_{n-1} \leq \cdots \leq \frac{n}{n+1} \cdot \frac{n-1}{n} \cdots \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{n+1}\to 0$

Also, since you were asked to show that the limit exists, rather than to calculate it, you can use the approach you suggested.  We have $S_{n+1} \leq \frac{n}{n+1} S_n \leq S_n$, so the sequence is nonincreasing, and bounded from below by $0$.  This implies that it has a limit.